# How do I add a parameter to an ajax GET request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I need to make multiple ajax requests and only display 10 items per page. The API here: https://www.mockapi.io/docs says: 
Add query params to GET requests:
/blogs?page=1&limit=10
I just don't understand where to put this in my ajax request(s). If I just put it in the URL it doesn't work. How do I do this? I've included my appropriate code.

```
let template = `
  {{#each items}}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{image}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{title}}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Price: &#36;{{price}}</p>
            <a href="#" data-name="{{title}}" data-price="{{price}}" class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
`;
```

```
function render(context) {
  let compiled = Handlebars.compile(template);
  itemsElement.innerHTML = compiled(context);
```

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://5ceb36a60c871100140bf873.mockapi.io/v1/item?page=1&limit=10',
method: 'GET'
}).done(function (resp) {
items = {items : resp}
render(items);
});
```

Next page button:

```
int page = 0;

function nextPage() {
  $.ajax({
    page += 1;
    url: 'http://5ceb36a60c871100140bf873.mockapi.io/v1/item?page=' + encodeURIComponent(page) + '&limit=10',
    method: 'GET'
    }).done(function (resp) {
    items = {items : resp}
    render(items);
    });
}
```

Comment: "If I just put it in the URL it doesn't work."  That's exactly where you put it.  If it "doesn't work", you should show us how you're doing that, and what the actual output is.  Your template code isn't relevant, but this detail is.  Also wouldn't hurt to show the actual HTTP request and response, as seen in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Ok I did it and that worked, I'm not sure what was going on earlier. Now I need to be able to change pages with next and previous buttons on my site. I know I don't have the buttons yet but how would I go about making another ajax request for the new items when pressing the button? There are 50 items total with 10 per page. Hopefully that makes sense, thank you in advance!

Comment: So it sounds like your question is, how to concatenate strings together?

Comment: I suppose. I know how to concatenate I just don't know how to approach this scenario. I was thinking having the url but instead have it like ```...?page=' + pageNumber + '&limit=10'``` I just don't know how to get this working.

Comment: Am I on the right track? I've added my attempt in the original post.

Comment: Yes, did you try it?  That's essentially what you should do.  (By the way, use `encodeURIComponent()` with any arbitrary data you put in the URL.  It doesn't matter for numbers, but if you start putting strings in there, you'll want to escape the text so that it can be used in the URL successfully.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194468/discussion-between-logan-defoe-and-brad).

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate section for url and parameter.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://5ceb36a60c871100140bf873.mockapi.io/v1/item',
   type: 'GET',
   data: 'page=1&limit=10',
}).done(function (resp) {
        items = {items : resp}
        render(items);
});
```